# How can I fix this linux issue?

Tags: linux

enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpFXM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrS4d.png)

These are the images of my code. When I compile the code using gcc command it gives me this error:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to` main'
/usr/tmp/ccftPNzM.o: In function `listFileRecursively': task12prog.c:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to` S_ISLINK'
task12prog.c:(.text+0x3ae): undefined reference to `listFilesRecursively'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How do I fix it?

Comment: First of all - please, remove images with code and add *whole* program code to your question. It's impossible to understand what you're doing. Also add exact gcc command you use. Do you have sys/stat.h included? Do you have main() function in your program? First error makes me suspect that you don't.

Answer (score 1):

`S_ISLINK` is a typo, it should be `S_ISLNK`. See [glibc documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html).